Android boot time with μs accuracy
It is a fact that both uptime -s and Kotlin:
object X {
  private val startTime = Clock.System.now()
  private val androidBootTime = startTime -
 SystemClock.elapsedRealtime().toDuration(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS)

with X referenced by an Application subclass,
returns an accuracy that is around ±10 seconds, ie. different invocations produce different boot times for the same boot session
Is there a Kotlin code-sample producing μs-accuracy boot time?
What is the highest attainable accuracy of Android boot time?
It is also a fact that determining the start time of your app can only be done by a static timestamp, all other intelligent means are defeated by Android caching and intentional slowness
Android boot uniqifiers
October 29 2024 update:
there is boot counter Android 7+ api level 24+
int boot_count = Settings.Global.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                        Settings.Global.BOOT_COUNT);

there is boot session uuid:
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id 
c4dfb88f-2a9a-49cf-a649-291b4969db88

there is btime, unix epoch second precision:
cat /proc/stat | grep btime
btime 1729814103

When a poor backup-battery Android boots up, time may be incorrect
apparently uptime -s reads
cat /proc/uptime 
408824.96 624814.45

so this in between two clock reads can obtain some kind of precision, like take average, round to nearest second or such if time difference is less than ms or so
The way forward is boot receiver and periodic uniqifier reads, the first estimated boot time value considered authoritative. empiric evidence to select method
UI issues
Android UI may restart, too. I have found two situations in logcat:

WATCHDOG kills a deadlocked UI thread
DeadSystemException

If an app has a background service with restart that should never exit, this may be detected
it might be helpful to stream logcat to sd card which is 150 MiB 1M lines per day
Conclusions October 29 22024
I will use a boot uniqifier and the first calculated boot time
That’s all Android can do.
.
boot counter works until reset 1…
boot UUID works
/proc/uptime is as bad as Android SystemClock.elapsedRealtime
/proc/stat is not readable without root permission but btime is accurate to the second (in a good battery real Android)
241105 for 2024 Android 12:

boot with bad back-up battery may start with inaccurate time
uptime -s and /proc/stat btime are obviously bad
after correcting system time via NTP from the Internet, both values change
therefore, any reference to Android boot time will suffer from an inaccuracy of ±10 seconds due to Android idiosyncrasies even when system time is highly accurate. The produced time may be different for different attempts
however, the boot uniquifiers work to distinguish boot events
the boot time estimate should not be acquired until system time is known to be accurate. For example, verify Android time accuracy to be better than 2 minutes by connecting to an https site or consulting NTP PTP NITZ GPS

Android time detection via NTP NITZ as of 2024 Android 12:

is only attempted every 18 hours
only corrects if time deviation more than 5 seconds
if NTP cannot be read within 3 minutes, Android waits another 18 hours
time update can be attempted within Android limitations by Settings — System — Date & time — Set time automatically to Off to On

if a recent NTP request somehow failed, it’s wait 18 hours or set time manually per the dumb Googlers’ design


it is not possible to force a time update other than Settings — System — Date & time

need to be signed by Google or system app


Note that if time is off 2 minutes or more, certificates will not work as in VPN may fail. Android connectivity check may then fail, so Android cannot connect to the Internet at all

Android with bad backup battery may start with time set to 1969
Then, the build-time of the operating system is used which may be 2022 or so
It is not until a timestamp can be obtained from a mobile system or the Internet that time is corrected



What is really dumb by them Googlers is the 5 seconds allowance. In 2024. Should be 1 ms. Costs nothing

Impact is a user-perceivable time error of ±5 seconds that is completely unnecessary. This is why Android does not show seconds: It’s a Pentagon-papers cover-up
Impact is that any timestamp reported by Android is ±10 seconds
If time error is allowed greater than 100 ms, users will notice, Google?

To claim that this is shitty and dumb and idiotic is an understatement. It’s Google trying to make Android safe without a plan
The way to set Android time December 1 2024
Android receives time from a host computer connected via adb

Time accuracy can be checked via Internet-ntp or a gps-fix
Plug in the device to adb, Settings — System — Date & time — Set time automatically: Off—On
If a failed ntp attempt was not made within preceding 18 hours and other conditions above, time will update to that of the host. It appears Android adb time has less restrictions compared to ntp time. Maybe time is always updated?
logcat will show:

2024-12-01 06:55:37.715566  1000  1900  1945 D
AlarmManagerService: Setting time of day to sec=1733064917
2024-12-01 06:55:17.423629  1000  1900  1900 D
ConditionProviders.SCP: onReceive android.intent.action.TIME_SET
2024-12-01 06:55:17.423826  1000  1900  1900 D
ConditionProviders.SCP: evaluateSubscriptionLocked
cal=ScheduleCalendar[mDays={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
mSchedule=ScheduleInfo{days=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
startHour=22, startMinute=0, endHour=7, endMinute=0,
exitAtAlarm=true,
nextAlarm=Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969 (0)}],
now=Sun Dec 01 06:55:17 PST 2024 (1733064917423),
nextUserAlarmTime=Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969 (0)
2024-12-01 06:55:17.433269  1000  1900  1957 I
UsageStatsService: User[0] Time changed in by -20 seconds
2024-12-01 06:55:17.548695  1000  1900  1957 I
UsageStatsDatabase: Time changed by -20s313ms. files deleted: 0 files moved: 19
2024-12-01 06:55:18.072561 10197 26701 26701 D
WM-RescheduleReceiver: Received intent Intent {
act=android.intent.action.TIME_SET flg=0x25200010
cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/
androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver }
2024-12-01 06:55:18.090800  1000  1900  1957 I
UsageStatsService: Time changed in by -20 seconds
2024-12-01 06:55:19.499607 10144  3084  3206 W
UsageSyncManager: <DWB> Last (TimeDelta{
wallTime=2024-11-30T19:32:34.447Z,
elapsedSinceBoot=PT52.836S},
boot count 30) and current (TimeDelta{
wallTime=2024-12-01T14:55:19.482Z,
elapsedSinceBoot=PT19H23M58.184S},
boot count 30) deltas are different.
Increase event shift by PT-20.313S.

To check device time, on macOS host do:
date "+%F %T%z" && adb shell date -In                      
2024-12-01 07:38:26-0800
2024-12-01T07:38:26,172221743-08:00

or, since macOS BSD cannot do nanoseconds:
python3 -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now().astimezone())';
adb shell date -In
2024-12-01 08:05:00.108809-08:00
2024-12-01T08:05:00,252027835-08:00


How have you measured that the accuracy is +/- 10 sec? It would also be helpful if you would explain what you want to do.

Unclear if you've seen: How to get the current time in native Android code? which would require NDK/JNI

I have an app that displays the value. If I run the app again without rebooting, the value is up to 7 seconds off. you can also run uptime -s repeatedly in Termux. I want to track unexpected Android reboots to make sure my Androids are stable. This is easier if the boot time is consistent. Maybe there is a boot uuid number like on Linux?

elapsedRealtime is ms precision, Clock.System.now is μs precision , meaning ±0.001001 s should be feasible. That would indicate that rounding to nearest 4 ms multiple should be feasible

If you want to capture the fact that the device rebooted see:Registering BOOT_COMPLETED receiver in Android 8 Just be aware that Android isn't an RTOS so accuracy is incidental.
